# jQuery objects and elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, types

I know I've seen a beautifully straightforward answer to a similar question before, but I haven't been able to remember or locate it, so apologies in advance.

I'm not new to coding, but I've had no formal training with Javascript/jQuery. Everything else I used has been strictly typed, so I'm still struggling with how JS does typing. I have a function that fires every time a child of a specific class is changed (I'm writing this for Sharepoint, so there is some working-around that has to be done.)

Why is it when I write this:

```
$(".listen *").change(function(event) {

        var element = event.target;

        if (element.title == 'Workstation')) {
             alert(element.val());
        }
    }
```

I get an error that .val() is not a function, and I have to instead write

```
 $(".listen *").change(function(event) {

        var element = event.target;

        if (element.title == 'Workstation')) {
             alert($('#' + element.id).val());
        }
     }
```

What is the difference between the object that "element" is and the object retrieved by using the id? Aren't they both jQuery objects? I realize that not all objects returned by my function might actually have a value to return, but I don't understand how the distinction is being made.

Thanks!

Comment: `element` refers to a DOM object, while wrapping it in `$` makes it a jQuery Object like `$(element)`. And `.val()` is a jQuery provided API not the DOM provided API.

Comment: As others have stated, it needs `$` to be a jQuery object. You might consider accessing the data using `$(this)` as you'd be assessing the jQuery object of the clicked element. Just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first code block the 'element' variable is not a jQuery object, it is a DOM object. The .val() method is not defined for DOM objects. It is only defined for jQuery objects.

In your second code block $('#' .element.id) returns a jQuery object that does have the val() method defined.

So to answer your question, No they are not both jQuery objects, only the second one is.

Comment: I can add comments now! This really helped me. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You must make jQuery object from your dom (`event.target`) like that;

```
$(".listen *").change(function(event) {

    var element = $(event.target);

    if (element.attr('title') == 'Workstation')) {
         alert(element.val());
    }
}
```

Then you can use your jQuery object as you want. By the way, if you want to catch the changed element, you can use `$(this)` instead of `$(event.target)`.

```
$(".listen *").change(function(event) {

    var element = $(this);

    if (element.attr('title') == 'Workstation')) {
         alert(element.val());
    }
}
```